# Android Java Bluetooth RSSI signal strength

Tags: android, bluetooth, rssi

I have problem about RSSI. I have reviewed resources from internet. But all of codes not working or I don't know way of the this. Just I want to receive the signal strength of the device that I connect via Bluetooth. Also, Am I need to use any a permission? Can you explain all of details about this? My codes as follows.

```
    private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            int  rssi = intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI,Short.MIN_VALUE);
            Toast.makeText(BtControl.this,"  RSSI: " + rssi + "dBm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
};

registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should register for `ACTION_FOUND` action. Change your registerreciever code to below.

```
registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
```

Also make sure you declare `BLUETOOTH_ADMIN` permission in the manifest file.

Comment: I defined receiver in activity. After I called registerReceiver in onCreate function. But not working. Where I doing wrong? What should I do?

Comment: Your intent filter is wrong. I have corrected it and added as an answer

Comment: Hello, I tried again. This time it's worked. I can't understand it's did'nt worked previously.